# Flutter fireabse_admob Missing google_app_id

Tags: flutter, admob

I searched and tryed some solutions but it didn't work for me.

AndroidManifest.xml bottom

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-xxxxx116788401~8xxxxxxxxx"/>
```

In AdvertClass

```
import 'dart:io';

class AdvertService {
  static final AdvertService _instance = AdvertService._internal();
  factory AdvertService() => _instance;
  MobileAdTargetingInfo _targetingInfo;
  final String _bannerAd = Platform.isAndroid
      ? 'ca-app-pub-6xxxxxxxxx01/xxxxxx5'
      : 'ca-app-pub-67xxxxxxxx01/2xxxxxx';

  AdvertService._internal() {
    _targetingInfo = MobileAdTargetingInfo();
  }
  showBanner() {
    print(_bannerAd);
    BannerAd banner = BannerAd(
        adUnitId: _bannerAd,
        size: AdSize.smartBanner,
        targetingInfo: _targetingInfo);

    banner
      ..load()
      ..show();
    banner.dispose();
  }
}
```

build.gradle file android to buttom

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.flutter_app"
        minSdkVersion 28
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"   
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

This code works with test id

```
 InterstitialAd(adUnitId: InterstitialAd.testAdUnitId , targetingInfo: _targetingInfo);
```

But when I change it to my admob id gives error

[Admob error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6IQ4H.png)

Also

```
I got verified Admob account.
I created key
I added my test device in 
 _targetingInfo = MobileAdTargetingInfo( testDevices: <String>["54a0a4f2"]);
```

Also I see it now it says

[Firebase error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ufF3.png)
but My pubsec.yaml gots

```
  firebase_admob: ^0.9.3+4
  firebase_auth: ^0.16.0
  cloud_firestore: ^0.13.5
  firebase_core: ^0.4.4+3
```

I createa firebase app ,downlaod the json file and add it then it says this steps but I can't find it

[Google json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBLPf.png)

Comment: Did you connect your firebase project to admob project ?

Comment: No I didn't create firebase project just admob

Answer (score 0):

The error Missing google_app_id is only because of you didn't implement Firebase Analytics, it is only a reminder, and it doesn't affect the ads.

Initialized AdMob with appID before showing the banner ad

```dart
FirebaseAdMob.instance.initialize(appId: appId);
```

Also set test device id [Found in your Admob error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6IQ4H.png) to prevent showing real ads in debug mode

```dart
MobileAdTargetingInfo(
  ...
  testDevices: <String>["Your device id"], // Android emulators are considered test devices
);
```

Real Ads will be shown by the following steps:

1. **Verified** AdMob ac.
2. [Sign Your App](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android)
3. Build **Release** if you have set your device test ID in Targeting Info.
4. [Connect to Firebase Project](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_admob#firebase-related-changes)

Comment: I got verified admob ac.
I create key
I change the constructor like  _targetingInfo = MobileAdTargetingInfo( testDevices: <String>["54a0a4f2"]);

Comment: I think I didn't 4.I create app and take it's id but also need to connect firebase